# Override site specific JavaScript right click context menu with browser specific right click context menu

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, contextmenu

Is there a way in Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer and/or Google Chrome to override the site specific right context menu (launched via JavaScript) so that the browser context menu shows instead?  I want to be able to use the browser add-on options in the context menu, but some sites don't allow this.  If you have any experience with any of these browsers, please respond and I will up-vote you.

One example:

Open Google Mail and right click a message in your inbox.

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't asked about Opera, it has a built-in setting for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site admins generally do this for security reasons. However, you can get around this easily if you know bit of HTML / JavaScript. Just tweak your 'mousedown' / 'click' handler. In case of jQuery, you might want to disable 'contextmenu' event.

There are some browser extensions to achieve this

- [Allow Right Click](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hompjdfbfmmmgflfjdlnkohcplmboaeo) fro Chrome
- [RightToClick](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/righttoclick/) for FireFox

Comment: What does this page mean with "security reasons"?

Comment: It means "to control you"

Comment: Removing bogus link on answer.